# What are the (if any) drawbacks of using CSS3 transform: scale on text for responsive headers?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a very elaborate header that uses lettering.js to style each individual letter.

Changing the text size with media queries would force me to change other aspect such as `top`, and `right` (relative) position as well as rotation and other styles separately.

I've found in webkit `transform: scale()` works well and scales all aspects of the design, not just the font size.

Do other browsers have bugs that make this a bad solution? It seems to have reasonably good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d), but I'm worried about bugs and pixelization on other browsers and rendering engines.

What are the (if any) drawbacks of using CSS3 transform: scale on text for responsive headers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues that I can think of:

1. The element will still take up its original size in the document, so you may need to use negative margins to deal with that. Here's a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/MwMYT/
2. Some browsers don't render scaled elements very well. Chrome is notorious for this (although it is most noticeable when transitioning the scale of an element). They are getting better though!

With that being said, I think your proposed solution is a reasonable one, and the drawbacks are certainly manageable!

Comment: Can you think of any more issues that might come up now that it's a year later? Or is the second issue fixed now?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I haven't done enough research, so I'm not sure how much the second point is still relevant. I'd also think that browser paint times would be effected by using the transform property, but once again, I'm not sure how much.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any, apart from browser support. `CSS transform` is good because it's hardware accelerated, so it's faster, and smoother.

Comment: "CSS transform is good because it's hardware accelerated, so it's faster, and smoother." relative to what?